# minimal correction of page number position

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering

I have to correct the position of the page number in the following way: 2,75mm away from the print space. One page 1 it should be 2,75mm to the right, on page 2 2,75mm to the left. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[english,showframe]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

\section{Seite}
\newpage
\section{Seite}
\setcounter{page}{11}
\newpage
\section{Seite}
\setcounter{page}{111}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `\pagemark`(provided by all KOMA-Script classes):

```
\documentclass[english]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\renewcommand*{%
  \pagemark
}{%
  {\usekomafont{pagenumber}{%
    \ifodd\value{page}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{2.75mm}\thepage}%
    \else
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\thepage\hspace{2.75mm}}%
    \fi
  }}}
\begin{document}
\section{Seite}
\newpage
\section{Seite}
\cleardoubleoddpage
\setcounter{page}{1001}% only to show the position for lage page numbers
\section{Seite}
\newpage
\section{Seite}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Offtopic: Loading package `geometry` changes the layout settings even if there are no options used. To avoid this calculations you have to use `geometry` option `pass`.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution with redefining pagemark is close but won't work with more digits. I corrected the MWE: Two- or three-digit pagenumbers should also be 2,75mm outside of the print space. Ragged-right on right pages, ragged-left on left pages

Comment: See my updated answer.